# using urllib2's urlopen method directly, vs passing urllib2.request to urlopen

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I'm a little bit confused about when should call urlopen directly, vs when should call request first and pass the result to open. The only thing I could come up with for sure, is I think one has to call request first if they want to specify a header parameter, but I think there is probably more to it then this.